# Filter array in ng-repeat with

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple question:
I have an array of object which i iterate trough in "ng-repeat":

**Object:**

```
  $scope.my objects= [
            { value: '1', text: 'lorem ipsum...1' },
            { value: '2', text: 'lorem impsum...2' },
            { value: '3', text: 'lorem ipsum...3' }
        ]
```

Now in my ng repeat i need to be able to set the status, so i have a select in which i have all available options:

**Option from my Select:**

```
 $scope.select_option= [
            { value: 'confirmed', text: 'confirmed' },
            { value: 'rejected', text: 'rejected' },
            { value: 'cancelled', text: 'cancelled' }
        ]
```

I would like to filter which options to display for each item of my my main object. This is an example of which filter i woul like in my select repeat.

```
 object.status == 'pending' && (object.start.getTime() >= new Date().getTime())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two ways to do this:

1. While iterating on the dom element use ng-if (Recommended way):

   `<div ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-if="object.status ===   'pending'>
   {object}
   </div>`
2. Or else you can use an angular filters:

   `<div ng-repeat="object in objects | custom_filter">
   </div>`

where you write your custom filter.